# Castle Windsor concrete type resolving and property injection

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm working with WPF.
I have several *view models* implementing a *interface* called `IPageView`.

The `MainViewModel` also implements `IPageView` and as 2 properties `LiveView` and `EditView`.

```
public MainViewModel : IPageView
{
    public LiveViewModel LiveView{ get; set; }
    public EditViewModel EditView{ get; set; }
}
```

I register components implementing `IPageView` like this:

```
Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IPageView>().WithServiceBase();
```

And i resolve all `IPageView` instances like this:

```
_container.ResolveAll<IPageView>();
```

I'd expect CastleWindsor to inject a instance of `LiveViewModel` to `LiveView` property, and a instance of `EditViewModel` to `EditView`.

This is not happening. Properties are null.

I don't like the idea to create specific new interfaces for each of my *viewmodel* just to correctly register and resolve the components.

In facts, I know i won't ever have more than one and only one *viewmodel* of type 'ILiveView' or 'IEditView' to choose from, hence i want to use the **concrete implementations**.

How can i configure the container to resolve my view models in `MainViewModel`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register like this:

```
Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IPageView>()
    .WithService.Base()
    .WithService.Self();
```